# Retrieve the unique websites from an url list

Tags: regex

I have a list with a lot of page urls. I want to retrieve the unique websites.

```
"http://www.gadgetgiants.com/products/mica-8-inch-touchscreen-android-2-3-tablet-wifi-1-2ghz-cpu-flash10-3"
"http://www.malma.mx/products/pan-digital"
"http://www.gadgetgiants.com/products/snowpad-7-capacitive-multi-touch-screen-android-2-3-tabletwifi-samsung-cortex-a8-1-2ghz-cpu-camera-1080p-external-3g"
"http://www.spiritualityandwellness.com/products/internalized-motivation"
"http://www.spiritualityandwellness.com/products/evergreen-motivation"
```

Will result to:

```
www.gadgetgiants.com
www.malma.mx
www.spiritualityandwellness.com
```

Answer (score 1):

`egrep -o  "www\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}" YOUR_FILE_NAME | sort -u`

got the regex from [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/grep-urls-717725/)

(Edit) **Example Usage and Output**

```
$ cat ur.txt
"http://www.gadgetgiants.com/products/mica-8-inch-touchscreen-android-2-3"
"http://www.malma.mx/products/pan-digital"
"http://www.gadgetgiants.com/products/snowpad-7-capacitive-multi-touch"
"http://www.spiritualityandwellness.com/products/internalized-motivation"
"http://www.spiritualityandwellness.com/products/evergreen-motivation"
"http://www.swellness.com.au/products/evergreen-motivation"

$ egrep -o "www\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}" ur.txt | sort -u
www.gadgetgiants.com
www.malma.mx
www.spiritualityandwellness.com
www.swellness.com.au
```

Comment: Does that remove duplicates as well?

Comment: Yes the last part `sort -u` will sort them and `-u` stands for **unique**

Comment: This does not match domain like .com.au

Answer (score 0):

Idea w/o regex:

Retrieve host from each address:

```
Uri uri = new Uri (yourLink);
string host = uri.Host;
```

Now you can just put all these hosts into HashSet or something.

Comment: C Sharp.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host.aspx  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx